# Detecting two keys pressed in quick succession

Tags: console, event-handling, linux, rust, device-driver

My computer has been having this issue where when I press a key, two key presses get registered. The goal of this program is to detect the time delta between the two keys so that I can set an effective debounce threshold. I also thought that it would be a good idea to try out Rust, so here it is:

```
use std::{mem, ptr, env, process, io};
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::Write;
use std::fs::File;
use std::collections::HashMap;

const EV_SYN: u16 = 0x00;
const EV_KEY: u16 = 0x01;

#[repr(C)]
struct LinuxTimeval {
    tv_sec: isize,
    tv_usec: isize,
}

impl LinuxTimeval {
    fn to_microseconds(&self) -> u64 {
        self.tv_sec as u64 * 1000000u64 + self.tv_usec as u64
    }
}

#[repr(C)]
struct LinuxInputEvent {
    time: LinuxTimeval,
    type_: u16,
    code: u16,
    value: i32,
}

fn read_struct_from_file<T: Sized>(file: &mut File) -> T {
    let mut buf = vec![0u8; mem::size_of::<T>()];
    match file.read(&mut buf) {
        Ok(sz) => assert!(sz == buf.len()),
        Err(err) => panic!("Unable to read from device: {}", err),
    }
    let ptr = &buf as &[u8] as *const [u8] as *const T;
    unsafe { ptr::read(ptr) }
}

fn read_events_from_file(file: &mut File) -> Vec<LinuxInputEvent> {
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    loop {
        let event: LinuxInputEvent = read_struct_from_file(file);
        if event.type_ == EV_SYN {
            if vec.len() > 0 {
                break;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        } else {
            vec.push(event);
        }
    }
    vec
}

fn process_key_event(event: &LinuxInputEvent,
                     last_occurence_per_key: &mut HashMap<u16, u64>,
                     threshold: u64) {
    let key = event.code;
    let micros = event.time.to_microseconds();
    match last_occurence_per_key.get(&key) {
        None => (),
        Some(last_micros) => {
            let delta = micros - last_micros;
            if delta < threshold {
                println!("Key code {:3}: event delta: {} us",
                         key, delta);
            }
        }
    }
    last_occurence_per_key.insert(key, micros);
}

fn print_usage_and_exit(program_name: &str) {
    writeln!(&mut io::stderr(), "Usage: {} <microseconds-delta>",
             program_name).unwrap();
    process::exit(1);
}

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();
    if args.len() != 2 { print_usage_and_exit(&args[0]); }
    let threshold: u64 = args[1].parse().unwrap_or(0);
    if threshold == 0 { print_usage_and_exit(&args[0]); }
    let mut file;
    match File::open("/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd") {
        Ok(f) => { file = f },
        Err(err) => panic!("Unable to open file: {}", err),
    }
    let mut last_occurence_per_key = HashMap::new();
    loop {
        match read_events_from_file(&mut file)
                .iter().find(|&event| event.type_ == EV_KEY && event.value == 1) {
            None => continue,
            Some(event) => process_key_event(event,
                                             &mut last_occurence_per_key,
                                             threshold),
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if any improvements can be made.

Comment: An interesting problem! I'm having a hard time generating keyboard events in a VM with Docker. I assume that's because none of it is going through the keyboard device! Do you have any suggestions on how I could generate those events to see that any suggested changes still work?

Comment: Try evtest, which simply dumps all the events from the device:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/evtest

Comment: Sorry, I think I was confusing — my problem is that nothing will ever be read from `/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd` because there is no real keyboard attached. I'm looking for a way to generate fake input events.

Comment: Apparently you can write "struct input_event" structures into the evdev device and it'll inject them as if they came from the device.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/evdev.c#L507

Answer (score 6):

#### Highlights

- Using the libc crate for C data types
- No heap allocation of read struct
- No (new) panics — better error handling
- Event iterator instead of vectors
- New types and traits to collect related functionality

**Beware** - I still haven't gotten this to actually read any events on my machine, but it does compile. That *should* be good enough, right? ^_^

#### libc crate

The [libc crate](http://doc.rust-lang.org/libc/libc/index.html) should *always* be used when interoperating with C code. This crate is guaranteed to have the correct sizes for platform-specific types.

Additionally, it already has a definition for `timeval`, so that was nice.

#### Less heap allocation

I used [`mem::uninitialized`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.uninitialized.html) to create an on-stack version of the struct with no values. I then got a reference to that area as bytes and read directly to that.

Note that I marked that function as unsafe - depending on what `T` resolves to, it could produce **very bad** results.

#### Error handling

Everywhere that had a `panic!` or `assert!` was changed into a `Result`. This allows the caller to decide how to deal with the error. The most awkward place left is in the call to `read_c_struct`, as it just stops the iterator on failure. Instead, it could return the `Result` directly and allow its caller to see the failure.

#### Embrace the Iterator

Rust *loves* iterators. This seemed like a perfect case for it - you have a stream of events and you want to do something based on them. I reworked your method into an `Iterator` implementation. This allows the caller to decide how much memory to allocate; in the final code, I believe it's very small. It also allows using the `filter` method and other iterator adaptors.

#### New types and traits

Iterators need a type to exist, and I also felt that your hashmap and threshold needed to live together. I also moved the read-specific methods into a new trait that is then implemented for all types that implement `Read`.

#### Complete code

There's a few comments scattered about for smaller things, but here it is:

```
extern crate libc;

use std::{mem, env, process, io, slice};
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::fs::File;
use std::collections::HashMap;

// Some helper methods for reading things
trait ReadExtensions : Read {
    /// Completely fill the supplied buffer
    fn read_complete(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<()> {
        let mut total_read = 0;
        while total_read < buf.len() {
            match self.read(&mut buf[total_read..]) {
                // Unable to read anything
                Ok(0) => return Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "Unable to read")),
                // Read some amount
                Ok(n) => total_read += n,
                // Might have been interrupted by something
                Err(ref e) if e.kind() == io::ErrorKind::Interrupted => {},
                Err(e) => return Err(From::from(e))
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    /// Directly read a C struct.
    ///
    /// Unsafe because only the concrete type of `T` can determine if
    /// the result is safe. Should only be used to read structs
    /// composed of primitive types without any pointers.
    unsafe fn read_c_struct<T>(&mut self) -> io::Result<T> {
        // avoid allocating on the heap
        let mut val = mem::uninitialized();
        let ptr = &mut val as *mut T as *mut u8;
        let mut buf = slice::from_raw_parts_mut(ptr, mem::size_of::<T>());

        try!(self.read_complete(buf));
        Ok(val)
    }
}

impl<R> ReadExtensions for R where R: io::Read {}



const EV_KEY: u16 = 0x01;

fn to_microseconds(tv: libc::timeval) -> u64 {
    // u64 suffix unneeded, adding _ for readability
    tv.tv_sec as u64 * 1_000_000 + tv.tv_usec as u64
}

// Using libc
#[derive(Copy,Clone)]
#[repr(C)]
struct LinuxInputEvent {
    time: libc::timeval,
    type_: libc::uint16_t,
    code: libc::uint16_t,
    value: libc::int32_t,
}

/// An iterator of Linux events
struct InputSource {
    file: File,
}

impl InputSource {
    fn new(path: &str) -> io::Result<InputSource> {
        let f = try!(File::open(path));
        Ok(InputSource { file: f })
    }
}

impl Iterator for InputSource {
    type Item = LinuxInputEvent;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<LinuxInputEvent> {
        unsafe { self.file.read_c_struct() }.ok()
    }
}

/// Tracks when multiple presses of the same key occurs and calls the
/// callback when duplicate events are triggered within a threshold.
struct KeyEventSink {
    last_occurences: HashMap<u16, u64>,
    threshold: u64,
}

impl KeyEventSink {
    fn new(threshold: u64) -> KeyEventSink {
        KeyEventSink {
            last_occurences: HashMap::new(),
            threshold: threshold,
        }
    }

    // Take a closure so we don't have to worry about user interface here
    fn process_event<F>(&mut self, event: LinuxInputEvent, f: F)
        where F: FnOnce(u16, u64)
    {
        let key = event.code;
        let micros = to_microseconds(event.time);

        // if-let for one useful match arm
        if let Some(last_micros) = self.last_occurences.get(&key) {
            let delta = micros - last_micros;
            if delta < self.threshold {
                f(key, delta)
            }
        }
        self.last_occurences.insert(key, micros);
    }
}

fn print_usage_and_exit(program_name: &str) {
    writeln!(&mut io::stderr(), "Usage: {} <microseconds-delta>", program_name).unwrap();
    process::exit(1);
}

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();
    if args.len() != 2 { print_usage_and_exit(&args[0]); }
    let threshold: u64 = args[1].parse().unwrap_or(0);
    if threshold == 0 { print_usage_and_exit(&args[0]); }

    // just use value of match
    let input = match InputSource::new("/dev/input/event2") {
        Ok(f) => f,
        Err(err) => panic!("Unable to open file: {}", err),
    };

    let mut sink = KeyEventSink::new(threshold);

    let key_events = input.filter(|&event| event.type_ == EV_KEY && event.value == 1);
    for key_event in key_events {
        sink.process_event(key_event, |key, delta| {
            println!("Key code {:3}: event delta: {} μs", key, delta);
        })
    }
}
```

#### Followups

> is there any particular reason you added the Copy and Clone traits to LinuxInputEvent?

Basically, `LinuxInputEvent` is a simple type comprised of `Copy`able values, and it's also fairly small in the grand scheme of things. Making it `Copy` simply improves the ergonomics of using it. If you implement `Copy`, you need to implement `Clone`.

> Seeing as the function is used at most once, FnOnce would also be better than Fn

Absolutely correct - I updated to use this.

I also updated the `read_complete` method a bit based on feedback from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31373055/155423).

Comment: Thanks for your improvements! I know how to use a lot more of the idioms now. I didn't expect partial reads due to the nature of the device but I guess it's good to include it anyways. I had no idea that trait extensions were a thing either. One question though: is there any particular reason you added the Copy and Clone traits to LinuxInputEvent?

Comment: The convention for simple generic bounds seems to be leaning back away from using `where`, yielding `fn process_event<F: Fn(u16, u64)>(…` (actually, with closures it may well be heading to using trait objects, but we’re not there yet). Seeing as the function is used at most once, `FnOnce` would also be better than `Fn`.

Comment: @gvl updated to address comments

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I don't know if I can get behind that shift. Once there's a second set of `<>` or `()` in the bounds, I don't think it's simple. Even if there are two different bounds, I don't think it's simple. I basically always use `where` now, because that lets me grow it without reorganizing my code. I basically only use `?Sized` in the declaration `<>`. The trait object part is surprising - those won't be optimized as aggressively, which makes me sad.